# What are ink sacs used for in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft Pocket Edition, I found a village and eventually found the End. Surprisingly, I found a chest with some ink sacs inside of it. I don't see anything that I can use it for in the crafting table now, so what is the purpose of the ink sacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're used as [dye](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool_Dye). If you have wool and you want to dye it black, use ink sacs.

They are also required in making [Written Books](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Written_Book) (not available in PE).

Answer (score 0):

They have yet to add a use for them in PE, because they don't have squids to drop them. They are only found in chests and that is a bug. You're not supposed to get them.